# How to save perticular part of the screen as image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have list of images of answer sheet in server.I need to display that images and need to select some particular area of that image, and save only that area as image. I done displaying and selection part but  i don't know how to save only that selected area as image. please help me as soon as possible.

[image: input]

[image: Output]

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  List<AnswerSheet> answerSheets = [
    AnswerSheet(
        imageUrl:
            'https://d18x2uyjeekruj.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Scan12.jpg',
        downloadedImagePath: '',
        selectedOffsets: List()),
    AnswerSheet(
        imageUrl:
            'https://d18x2uyjeekruj.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Scan12.jpg',
        downloadedImagePath: '',
        selectedOffsets: List())
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: GestureDetector(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                EntryItem(answerSheets[index]),
            itemCount: answerSheets.length,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class EntryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnswerSheet answerSheet;

  EntryItem(this.answerSheet);

  @override
  _EntryItemState createState() => _EntryItemState();
}

class _EntryItemState extends State<EntryItem> {
  final GlobalKey _myCanvasKey = new GlobalKey();
  MyCustomPainter _customPainter;
  Offset _startOffset;
  bool isLoading = true;
  ui.Image _image;
  bool _isImageEditable = true;
  BuildContext context;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _downloadImage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    if (isLoading) {
      return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
    } else {
      return GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: CustomPaint(
                key: _myCanvasKey,
                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
                painter: _customPainter,
              ),
            ),
          ));
    }
  }

  Future downloadAndSaveImage(AnswerSheet answerSheet) async {
    print("downloading....");
    var response = await get(answerSheet.imageUrl);
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = File(join(documentDirectory.path, '${DateTime.now()}.jpg'));
    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    answerSheet.downloadedImagePath = file.path;
    print(file.path);
    return response.bodyBytes;
  }

  Future<Null> _downloadImage() async {
    List<int> img = await downloadAndSaveImage(widget.answerSheet);
    _image = await _loadImage(img);
    setState(() {
      _customPainter =
          MyCustomPainter(answerSheet: widget.answerSheet, image: _image);
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _loadImage(List<int> img) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  Rect getRect(Offset offset) {
    return Rect.fromPoints(offset, Offset(offset.dx + 30, offset.dy + 30));
  }

  _onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails detailData) {
    if (_isImageEditable) {
      _startOffset = detailData.globalPosition;
      widget.answerSheet.selectedOffsets.add(_startOffset);
    }
  }

  _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails detailData) {
    if (_isImageEditable) {
      widget.answerSheet.selectedOffsets
          .add(Offset(detailData.localPosition.dx, _startOffset.dy));
      _myCanvasKey.currentContext.findRenderObject().markNeedsPaint();
    }
  }

  _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    print('_onHorizontalDragEnd');
    if (_isImageEditable) {
      _myCanvasKey.currentContext.findRenderObject().markNeedsPaint();
      _startOffset = null;
    }
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final AnswerSheet answerSheet;
  final ui.Image image;

  MyCustomPainter({this.answerSheet, this.image});

  Paint _paint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.3)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

  Offset _prvOffset;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _paint.strokeWidth = 40;
    Rect myRect = Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(size.width, size.height);
    drawImage(myRect, size, canvas, new Paint(), BoxFit.fill);
    if (answerSheet.selectedOffsets.length != 0) {
      for (Offset currOffset in answerSheet.selectedOffsets) {
        if (_prvOffset != null && currOffset != null)
          canvas.drawLine(_prvOffset, currOffset, _paint);
        _prvOffset = currOffset;
      }
      _prvOffset = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  Paint getPaint(Color color) {
    return new Paint()
      ..isAntiAlias = true
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  }

 

  void drawImage(
      Rect outputRect, Size size, Canvas canvas, Paint paint, BoxFit fit) {
    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    final FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(fit, imageSize, outputRect.size);
    final Rect inputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
    final Rect outputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, outputRect);
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, paint);
  }
}

class AnswerSheet {
  String imageUrl;
  String downloadedImagePath;
  List<Offset> selectedOffsets;

  AnswerSheet({this.imageUrl, this.downloadedImagePath, this.selectedOffsets});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)

A simple plugin to capture widgets as Images.

This plugin wraps your widgets inside RenderRepaintBoundary

This handy plugin can be used to capture any Widget including full screen screenshots & individual widgets like Text().

Comment: but in my problem that is not a text, this is an image inside the canvas, and i  need that highlighted part only. don't want entire screen

Comment: it will save the part you want

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to use [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) or [crop](https://pub.dev/packages/crop) packages. These are helpful to you. Look at the below example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ImageCropper',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: 'ImageCropper',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({this.title});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

enum AppState {
  free,
  picked,
  cropped,
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AppState state;
  File imageFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = AppState.free;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: imageFile != null ? Image.file(imageFile) : Container(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        onPressed: () {
          if (state == AppState.free)
            _pickImage();
          else if (state == AppState.picked)
            _cropImage();
          else if (state == AppState.cropped) _clearImage();
        },
        child: _buildButtonIcon(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButtonIcon() {
    if (state == AppState.free)
      return Icon(Icons.add);
    else if (state == AppState.picked)
      return Icon(Icons.crop);
    else if (state == AppState.cropped)
      return Icon(Icons.clear);
    else
      return Container();
  }

  Future<Null> _pickImage() async {
    imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _cropImage() async {
    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: imageFile.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: Platform.isAndroid
            ? [
                CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
              ]
            : [
                CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio7x5,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
              ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          title: 'Cropper',
        ));
    if (croppedFile != null) {
      imageFile = croppedFile;
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.cropped;
      });
    }
  }

  void _clearImage() {
    imageFile = null;
    setState(() {
      state = AppState.free;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to crop programmatically